# Pointing a multiple subdomains to same heroku application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, subdomain

I'm trying to make subdomains for my main app, such as *blog.mysite.com* and *podcast.mysite.com*.  There are resources in the main app that I want to have easy access to in my blog and my podcast subdomains.  I also want users to be able to log in on both of these subdomains as well.  For this reason, I've built both the blog and podcast into the same main application, accessing the same database.  These subdomains are specified with subdomain constraints in my routes file like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  constraints subdomain: 'blog' do
    match '/', to: 'blog_posts#index', via: :get
    resources 'blog_posts', path: 'posts'
  end

  constraints subdomain: 'podcast' do
    match '/', to: 'podcasts#index', via: :get
    resources 'podcasts'
  end

  constraints subdomain: ['www', ''] do
    # my other resources
  end
end
```

Now that I have everything working locally, I'm trying to configure it properly with Heroku and DNSimple.  I have a CNAME record pointing from *mysite.com* to *mysite.herokuapp.com*, which works when no subdomains are added.  I'd like to be able to just similarly point *blog.mysite.com* to *mysite.herokuapp.com*, since all functionality is based on the url that is being pulled.

However, when I visit *blog.mysite.com*, it seems to be properly pointing to *mysite.herokuapp.com*, but I receive a message saying the Heroku app doesn't exist.  This doesn't make sense to me because it's essentially the same application that I'm running locally, which accepts the *blog* subdomain and works how I want it to.

Comment: Hi. Have you customized your app domain @`heroku`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I visit blog.mysite.com, it seems to be properly pointing to mysite.herokuapp.com, but I receive a message saying the Heroku app doesn't exist.

That error means you haven't configured the domain at Heroku. Remember to add `blog.mysite.com` in Heroku using the [`domains:add` command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain).